# Use a variable for Highcharts yAxis.Max

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Im trying to pass a variable('maxValue') into my Highcharts guage . I cant get the variable to pass in successfully, the graph renders but without the value.

Ive tried Number and parseInt Functions but neither make a difference.

I setup a JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/d5d4cgbe/16/

The code section in question:

```
var maxValue = 120; //set the maxValue var

 $('#visitPerformanceWeek').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: maxValue,
                title: {
                    text: 'Hours Worked'
                }
            },
```

I will eventually be passing a value collected from an AJAX request, this part I have working but have excluded from the fiddle to keep it simple. Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting the `maxValue` dynamically, something like **[setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis--setExtremes)** should do it. Try

```
chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0,maxValue);
```

Another alternative is the update method:

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({ max: maxValue });
```

For the `maxValue` to be displayed by the solidgauge, you need to specify a `tickerInterval` which divides into the maxValue. Presently, the chart is generating a default tick interval e.g. 10, which adds up to 100. For example, a `maxValue` of 120, you may set the `tickInterval` to 12

```
   yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 120,
        tickInterval: 12,
        ...
   }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/cfdcca63/)**

Comment: Thanks. Using setExtremes redraws the chart automatically (i believe) this is working now. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/d5d4cgbe/23/

you can set value using following command :

```
chart.yAxis.max = maxValue;
```

check browser console for yAxis value.

Comment: Thanks, I can see this updating in the console. But the chart doest actually use the value. Perhaps i need to re render it somehow!